# Textbox text change event not firing when text changed from code

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox whose text is expected to be changed from the jquery code.

It is not firing when the value assinged from jquery code however it
is  firing when I change the text by key press.

Below is HTML and JQuery which i am using

```html
<input type="text" id="txtProjectName"/>
```

```js
 $("#txtProjectName").on('change keyup paste mouseup', function () {
        alert('Changed');
    });
```

What modifications would require here? please assist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***It is not firing when the value assinged from jquery code***

Programmatically changing the value of an input doesn't fire its change event. You'll have to do that yourself using [**.trigger()**](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

You need need to trigger change event when changing value from code

```
 $("#txtProjectName").val('Whatever').trigger('change');
```